# Spark streaming from Kafka returns result on local but not on YARN

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-kafka, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-cdh

I am using Cloudera's VM CDH 5.12, **spark v1.6**, kafka(installed by yum) v0.10 and python 2.66. I am following this [link](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/spark_streaming.html#streaming)

spark settings:

[image]

Below is a simple spark application that I am running. It takes events from kafka and prints it after map reduce.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print("Usage: kafka_wordcount.py <zk> <topic>", file=sys.stderr)
        exit(-1)

    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingKafkaWordCount")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)
zkQuorum, topic = sys.argv[1:]
kvs = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, "spark-streaming-consumer", {topic: 1})
lines = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])
counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) \
    .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
    .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
counts.pprint()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

**Please Note that, When I submit above code using following command(local) it runs fine**

```
spark-submit --master local[2] --jars /usr/lib/spark/lib/spark-examples.jar testfile.py <ZKhostname>:2181 <kafka-topic>
```

**When I submit same above code using following command(YARN) it doesn't work**

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --jars /usr/lib/spark/lib/spark-examples.jar testfile.py <ZKhostname>:2181 <kafka-topic>
```

Here is the log generated when ran on YARN(cutting them short, logs may differ from above mentioned spark settings):

```
 INFO Client: 
client token: N/A
diagnostics: N/A
ApplicationMaster host: 192.168.134.143
ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
queue: root.cloudera
start time: 1515766709025
final status: UNDEFINED
tracking URL: http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1515761416282_0010/
user: cloudera

40 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Application application_1515761416282_0010 has started running.
40 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 53694.
40 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 53694
53 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after waiting maxRegisteredResourcesWaitingTime: 30000(ms)
54 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager quickstart.cloudera:56220 with 534.5 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(1, quickstart.cloudera, 56220)
07 INFO ReceiverTracker: Starting 1 receivers
07 INFO ReceiverTracker: ReceiverTracker started
07 INFO PythonTransformedDStream: metadataCleanupDelay = -1
07 INFO KafkaInputDStream: metadataCleanupDelay = -1
07 INFO KafkaInputDStream: Slide time = 10000 ms
07 INFO KafkaInputDStream: Storage level = StorageLevel(false, false, false, false, 1)
07 INFO KafkaInputDStream: Checkpoint interval = null
07 INFO KafkaInputDStream: Remember duration = 10000 ms
07 INFO KafkaInputDStream: Initialized and validated org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaInputDStream@7137ea0e
07 INFO PythonTransformedDStream: Slide time = 10000 ms
07 INFO PythonTransformedDStream: Storage level = StorageLevel(false, false, false, false, 1)
07 INFO PythonTransformedDStream: Checkpoint interval = null
07 INFO PythonTransformedDStream: Remember duration = 10000 ms
07 INFO PythonTransformedDStream: Initialized and validated org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.PythonTransformedDStream@de77734

10 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2 stored as values in memory (estimated size 5.8 KB, free 534.5 MB)
10 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 3.5 KB, free 534.5 MB)
20 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1515766760000 ms
30 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1515766770000 ms
40 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1515766780000 ms
```

After this, the job just starts repeating following lines(after some delay set by stream context) and doesnt printout kafka's stream, whereas job on master local with the exact same code does.

[image]

**Interestingly** it prints following line every-time a kafka event occurs(picture is of increased spark memory settings)

[image]

Note that:

- Data is in kafka and I can see that in consumer console
- I have also tried increasing executor's momory(3g) and network
  timeout time(800s) but no success